# Laravel API Actions Being Performed from non API Domains

Tags: laravel

Laravel version 8.19.0.

I'm playing around with a fresh Laravel installation to test out Sanctum and I've set up some routes in my routes/api.php file:

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function() {
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@index');
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/users/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@fetch');
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->put('/users/{user}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@update');
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->delete('/users/{user}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@destroy');
});
```

As well as this, I've altered the RouteServiceProvider so that these api routes work through an "api" subdomain:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::domain(env('API_DOMAIN'))
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

From the .env file:

```
API_DOMAIN=http://api.laravel-sanctum.com
```

Whilst testing my routes out, I've noticed that I can access the actions from my api routes, even when I attempt them from the web domains (which use a "test" subdomain).

For example: Laravel will perform the index action in the UsersController when I attempt to access both api.laravel-sanctum.com/v1/users AND test.laravel-sanctum.com/v1/users.

Can anybody enlighten me as to why this is happening and how I can prevent the test.laravel-sanctum.com/users URL from executing the index action in UsersController?

Happy to supply any further information if required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the reason why this was happening was because `env('API_DOMAIN')` was returning null in the RouteServiceProvider as I had ran `php artisan config:cache` at some point. By running `php artisan config:clear`, the env variable correctly returned the api domain and the routes worked as intended.

It is worth pointing out for anyone else viewing this that I've also since learned that Laravel recommends that you only use env variables within config files, and refer to the config files outside of that within your appllication. I.e. it's recommended to use `env('API_DOMAIN')` within a config file and refer to said config variable instead in the RouteServiceProvider.